# alignment is not working in phpWord TemplateProcessor

Tags: laravel, phpword

I am trying to change the alignment of the image added into the docx file, but the alignment is not working. I have tried as below:

```
$templateProcessor->setImageValue($tag->template_tag, 
                       array(
                                                        
                          'path' => $filePath, 
                          'positioning' => \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Image::POSITION_ABSOLUTE,
                          'alignment' => \PhpOffice\PhpWord\SimpleType\Jc::END,
                         )
                        );
```

Though the image is rendered in exported docx file, however the image alignment is always left. How can I change the alignment of image to either center or end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using positionning settings reserved when [you create a Word document from scratch using the library](https://phpword.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes.html#create-float-left-image).

However, you are using PHPWord **templating processing capability** : that means the **layout is driven by your Word document itself**.

So, the **placeholder itself** must be **centered in the template** to be replaced by a centered image.

To illustrate, consider the code below (placed in any PHP code where `TemplateProcessor` class is available) :

```php
$templateProcessor = new TemplateProcessor('Template.docx');
$templateProcessor->setValue('mc', 'Word MC');
$templateProcessor->setImageValue(
    'advisory', 
    [
        'path' => 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/33/Parental_Advisory_label.svg/300px-Parental_Advisory_label.svg.png'
    ]
    );
$templateProcessor->saveAs('Replaced.docx');
```

With the following Word template (`Template.docx` in the code)...
[image]
...you got the following replacement (`Replaced.docx` in the code)
[image]

If you center the image placeholder...
[image]
...the replace image is centered !
[image]

The second argument, named `$replace`, of the method `setImageValue` of the `TemplateProcessor` class (added in the [0.16 version](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/0.16.0/src/PhpWord/TemplateProcessor.php#L481)) can be an associative array but it only supports 3 values (quoted from the docBlock of the method) :

```php
@param mixed $replace Path to image, or array("path" => xx, "width" => yy, "height" => zz)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. However, if I have ${advisory} text in multiple pages, it is only replacing the first occurred ${advisory} text, others are not changed. How can I replace all ${advisory}  text with a image ?

Comment: @Suman I tested it : if you repeat the same placeholder all over the template, **all occurences of the placeholder** are correctly replaced. Tested with latest version to date : 0.18.2